# Don't get clickEvent in my Table

Tags: gwt, onclick, flextable

in my GWT app I've got a very annoing problem.

I bulid some own widgets. One is a table with a scrollable content and a fixed header. To Display the data I put another FlexTable in it. 
Now when I register a ClickHandler to the DataFlexTable, I don't get any event there.

How I can get the clickEvent in the FlexTable inside the scrollTable ? 
Code for ScrollTable and ResizingFunction is below.

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance ;)

ScrollTable:

```
    /**
 * ScrollTable.java
 * 


import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Style.TextAlign;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Style.Unit;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.TableCellElement;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.TableRowElement;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Element;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Event;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ComplexPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FlexTable;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;

/**
 * 
 * @author warzok
 */
public class ScrollTable
    extends ComplexPanel
    implements ResizeableTableInterface

{
  private Element mainElem;
  private FlexTable headerTable;
  private FlexTable dataTable;
  private int headerColumn = 0;
  private final String DATAATTRIBUTE = "data-column-width";
  private Element headerWrapper;
  private Element dataWrapper;
  private Element absoluteElem;
  private com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element mockScrollable;
  private ResizeHandler resizeHandler;

  /**
   * 
   */
  public ScrollTable()
  {
    this( new FlexTable(), new FlexTable() );
  }

  public ScrollTable( FlexTable headerTable, FlexTable dataTable )
  {
    mainElem = DOM.createDiv();
    setElement( mainElem );
    mainElem.getStyle().setHeight( 600.0, Unit.PX );
    setStylePrimaryName( "scrollFlexTable" );
    this.headerTable = headerTable;
    this.dataTable = dataTable;
  }

  /**
   * Used to center the headertitle in the middle of column
   */
  public void centerHeader()
  {
    headerTable.getElement().getStyle().setTextAlign( TextAlign.CENTER );
  }

  public void initTable()
  {
    // Create the main div container
    DOM.setStyleAttribute( mainElem, "padding", "0px" );
    DOM.setStyleAttribute( mainElem, "overflow", "hidden" );
    DOM.setStyleAttribute( mainElem, "position", "relative" );

    // Wrap the table wrappers in another div
    absoluteElem = DOM.createDiv();
    absoluteElem.getStyle().setProperty( "position", "absolute" );
    absoluteElem.getStyle().setProperty( "top", "0px" );
    absoluteElem.getStyle().setProperty( "left", "0px" );
    absoluteElem.getStyle().setProperty( "width", "100%" );
    absoluteElem.getStyle().setProperty( "padding", "0px" );
    absoluteElem.getStyle().setProperty( "margin", "0px" );
    absoluteElem.getStyle().setProperty( "border", "0px" );
    absoluteElem.getStyle().setProperty( "overflow", "hidden" );
    absoluteElem.getStyle().setProperty( "height", "100%" );
    mainElem.appendChild( absoluteElem );

    // Create the table wrapper and spacer
    headerWrapper = createWrapper( "headerWrapper" );
    dataWrapper = createWrapper( "dataWrapper" );
    dataWrapper.getStyle().setProperty( "height", "100%" );

    // Create an element to determine the scroll bar width
    mockScrollable = com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element.as( dataWrapper.cloneNode( false ) );
    mockScrollable.getStyle().setProperty( "position", "absolute" );
    mockScrollable.getStyle().setProperty( "top", "0px" );
    mockScrollable.getStyle().setProperty( "left", "0px" );
    mockScrollable.getStyle().setProperty( "width", "100px" );
    mockScrollable.getStyle().setProperty( "height", "100px" );
    mockScrollable.getStyle().setProperty( "visibility", "hidden" );
    mockScrollable.getStyle().setProperty( "overflow", "scroll" );
    mockScrollable.getStyle().setProperty( "zIndex", "-1" );
    absoluteElem.appendChild( mockScrollable );

    // Adopt the header and data tables into the panel
    adoptTable( headerTable, headerWrapper, 0 );
    adoptTable( dataTable, dataWrapper, 1 );

    dataTable.getElement().getStyle().setProperty( "height", "100%" );
    dataTable.getElement().getStyle().setProperty( "paddingBottom", "20px" );


    // Add some event handling
    sinkEvents( Event.ONMOUSEOUT );
    DOM.setEventListener( dataWrapper, this );
    DOM.sinkEvents( dataWrapper, Event.ONSCROLL );
    getResizeHandler().setCheckElem( dataWrapper );
    DOM.sinkEvents( dataWrapper, Event.ONCLICK );
    DOM.setEventListener( headerWrapper, this );
    DOM.sinkEvents( headerWrapper, Event.ONMOUSEMOVE | Event.ONMOUSEDOWN | Event.ONMOUSEUP
        | Event.ONCLICK );

  }

  @Override
  public void onBrowserEvent( Event event )
  {
    adjustSize();
    boolean callSuper = getResizeHandler().onBrowserEvent( event );
    if ( callSuper )
    {
      super.onBrowserEvent( event );
    }
  }

  /**
   * Adopt a table into this {@link AbstractScrollTable} within its wrapper.
   * 
   * @param table
   *          the table to adopt
   * @param wrapper
   *          the wrapper element
   * @param index
   *          the index to insert the wrapper in the main element
   */
  private void adoptTable( Widget table, Element wrapper, int index )
  {
    DOM.insertChild( absoluteElem, wrapper, index );
    add( table, wrapper );
  }

  /**
   * @param styleName
   * @return
   */
  private Element createWrapper( String styleName )
  {
    Element elm = DOM.createDiv();
    elm.setClassName( styleName );
    return elm;
  }

  public FlexTable getHeader()
  {
    return headerTable;
  }

  public void setHeader( FlexTable header )
  {
    this.headerTable = header;
  }

  public void addHeaderWidget( Widget widget )
  {
    headerTable.setWidget( 0, headerColumn, widget );
    headerColumn++;
  }

  public void addDataWidget( int row, int column, Widget widget )
  {
    dataTable.setWidget( row, column, widget );
  }

  /**
   * 
   */
  private void adjustColumnSize()
  {
    for ( int i = 0; i < dataTable.getCellCount( 4 ); i++ )
    {
      Element elm = dataTable.getCellFormatter().getElement( 4, i );
      dataTable.getColumnFormatter().getElement( i )
          .setAttribute( DATAATTRIBUTE, "" + elm.getClientWidth() );
      dataTable.getColumnFormatter().setWidth( i,
          dataTable.getColumnFormatter().getElement( i ).getAttribute( DATAATTRIBUTE ) + "px" );
      headerTable.getColumnFormatter().setWidth( i,
          dataTable.getColumnFormatter().getElement( i ).getAttribute( DATAATTRIBUTE ) + "px" );
    }
  }

  public void adjustSize()
  {
    DOM.setElementAttribute( dataTable.getElement(), DATAATTRIBUTE, "" + dataTable.getOffsetWidth() );
    adjustColumnSize();
    resizeHeader();
  }

  protected void resizeHeader()
  {
    for ( int i = 0; i < dataTable.getCellCount( 0 ); i++ )
    {
      String width = dataTable.getColumnFormatter().getElement( i ).getAttribute( DATAATTRIBUTE );
      headerTable.getColumnFormatter().setWidth( i, width );
    }
  }

  public FlexTable getDataTable()
  {
    return dataTable;
  }

  public void setDataTable( FlexTable dataTable )
  {
    this.dataTable = dataTable;
  }

  public FlexTable getHeaderTable()
  {
    return headerTable;
  }

  public void setHeaderTable( FlexTable headerTable )
  {
    this.headerTable = headerTable;
  }

  public Element getHeaderWrapper()
  {
    return headerWrapper;
  }

  public void setHeaderWrapper( Element headerWrapper )
  {
    this.headerWrapper = headerWrapper;
  }

  @Override
  public void resizeColumn( int column, int columnWidth )
  {
    headerTable.getColumnFormatter().getElement( column )
        .setAttribute( "width", columnWidth + "px" );
    dataTable.getColumnFormatter().getElement( column ).setAttribute( "width", columnWidth + "px" );
  }

  @Override
  public boolean hasToChangeCurser( TableCellElement tableCellElement, TableRowElement tr )
  {
    return tr == getTableHeadElement();
  }

  private TableRowElement getTableHeadElement()
  {
    return headerTable.getRowFormatter().getElement( 0 ).cast();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean hasSelectedElement( TableRowElement tr )
  {
    return tr == null;
  }

  protected ResizeHandler getResizeHandler()
  {
    if ( resizeHandler == null )
    {
      resizeHandler = new ResizeHandler( this );
    }
    return this.resizeHandler;
  }

}
```

Here is the code for the ResizeHandler:

```
public class ResizeHandler
{
  private int mouseDownX;
  private boolean mouseDown;
  private int columnWidth;
  private TableCellElement headerElem;
  private int column;
  private ResizeMode resizeMode;
  private ResizeableTableInterface resizeableTable;
  private Element checkElem;

  /**
   * @param resizeableTable
   */
  public ResizeHandler( ResizeableTableInterface resizeableTable )
  {
    super();
    this.resizeableTable = resizeableTable;
  }

  /**
   * Hier wird versuch zu resizen
   * 
   * @param event
   *          das Event
   * @return true wenn die superMethode gerufen werden soll
   */
  public boolean onBrowserEvent( Event event )
  {
    if ( event.getType().equals( "change" ) )
    {
      return true;
    }

    boolean eventMouseUp = event.getType().equals( "mouseup" );
    boolean eventClick = event.getType().equals( "click" );
    boolean eventMouseDown = event.getType().equals( "mousedown" );
    boolean eventMouseMove = event.getType().equals( "mousemove" );
    if ( checkElem != null )
    {
      if ( eventClick && event.getCurrentEventTarget().equals( checkElem ) )
      {
        return true;
      }
    }
    if ( eventMouseUp )
    {
      mouseDownX = -1;
      mouseDown = false;
    }
    if ( resizeMode == ResizeMode.RESIZING && eventClick )
    {
      resizeMode = ResizeMode.ENDING;
    }

    TableCellElement tableCellElement = findNearestParentCell( (Element) event.getEventTarget()
        .cast() );
    if ( tableCellElement == null )
    {
      return true;
    }

    Element trElem = tableCellElement.getParentElement();
    if ( trElem == null )
    {
      return true;
    }
    TableRowElement tr = TableRowElement.as( trElem );

    if ( resizeableTable.hasSelectedElement( tr ) )
    {
      return true;
    }

    if ( resizeableTable.hasToChangeCurser( tableCellElement, tr ) )
    {
      changeCurser( event, tableCellElement, eventMouseDown, eventMouseMove );
    }
    else
    {
      return true;
    }

    if ( headerElem != null && eventMouseMove && mouseDown )
    {
      int move = event.getClientX() - mouseDownX;
      @SuppressWarnings ( "hiding")
      int columnWidth = this.columnWidth + move;
      if ( columnWidth > 24 )
      {
        resizeableTable.resizeColumn( column, columnWidth );
        resizeMode = ResizeMode.RESIZING;
      }
    }

    if ( resizeMode != ResizeMode.RESIZING && resizeMode != ResizeMode.ENDING && eventClick )
    {
      return true;
    }
    else if ( resizeMode == ResizeMode.ENDING )
    {
      resizeMode = ResizeMode.NO;
    }
    return false;
  }

  /**
   * Verändert das Aussehen des Cursers
   */
  protected void changeCurser( Event event, TableCellElement tableCellElement,
      boolean eventMouseDown, boolean eventMouseMove )
  {
    int mouseX = event.getClientX();
    int right = tableCellElement.getAbsoluteLeft() + tableCellElement.getOffsetWidth();
    if ( !mouseDown && eventMouseDown )
    {
      if ( mouseX <= right && mouseX >= right - 10 )
      {
        headerElem = tableCellElement;
        column = tableCellElement.getCellIndex();
        mouseDownX = event.getClientX();
        mouseDown = true;
        columnWidth = headerElem.getOffsetWidth();
      }
    }
    else if ( eventMouseMove )
    {
      if ( mouseDown || mouseX <= right && mouseX >= right - 10 )
      {
        tableCellElement.getStyle().setCursor( Cursor.COL_RESIZE );
      }
      else
      {
        tableCellElement.getStyle().setCursor( Cursor.AUTO );
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Diese Methode ist 1 zu 1 aus der Oberklasse übernommen. Nicht ändern!!!
   */
  private TableCellElement findNearestParentCell( Element elem )
  {
    while ( (elem != null) && (elem != resizeableTable.getElement()) )
    {
      String tagName = elem.getTagName();
      if ( "td".equalsIgnoreCase( tagName ) || "th".equalsIgnoreCase( tagName ) )
      {
        return elem.cast();
      }
      elem = elem.getParentElement();
    }
    return null;
  }

  public Element getCheckElem()
  {
    return checkElem;
  }

  public void setCheckElem( Element checkElem )
  {
    this.checkElem = checkElem;
  }

}
```

Code ResizeableTableInterface:

```
public interface ResizeableTableInterface
{


  public com.google.gwt.user.client.Element getElement();

  boolean hasToChangeCurser(TableCellElement tableCellElement, TableRowElement tr );

  /**
   * @param column
   * @param columnWidth
   */
  public void resizeColumn( int column, int columnWidth );

  /**
   * @param tr
   * @return
   */
  public boolean hasSelectedElement( TableRowElement tr );
}
```

ResizeMode:

```
public enum ResizeMode
{
  NO,
  RESIZING,
  ENDING
}
```